# How to use antd theme tokens in my custom component?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, antd

I want to use [antd theme tokens](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) to style my custom component? May be there is an emotion-like way:

```
// style.ts
export default createStyles((token) => ({
  foo: {
    color: token.colorPrimary,
  }
})

// index.tsx
import styles from './style';

const FooBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.foo}>
      FooBar
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or maybe there is a better way to do it? There is practically nothing in the docs except useToken and use in style directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import `theme` from antd and use it as a hook:

```
import { theme as antdTheme } from 'antd'

function MyComponent() {
  const { useToken } = antdTheme
  const { token: theme } = useToken() 

  // now use it
  return (<div 
    style={{
      color: theme.colorPrimary
    }}>
      styled div
  </div>)
}
```

Or you can create a styles file (keeping your styles separated from your components/functions) and use it like this:

```
// styles.ts
import { CSSProperties } from 'react'
import { theme as antdTheme } from 'antd'

// if you use TS you must declare types here
type StylesType = {
  DivStyle: CSSProperties
  OtherComponentStyle: CSSProperties
}

function Styles(): StylesType {
  const { useToken } = antdTheme
  const { token: theme } = useToken()

  const DivStyle = {
    color: theme.colorPrimary
  }

  ... other components


  return {
    DivStyle,
    ... other components
  }
}

export default
```

And use it like this:

```
// MyComponent.tsx
import Styles from 'path/to/styles'

function MyComponent() {
  const S = Styles()

  // now use it
  return (
    <div 
      style={S.DivStyle}
    >
        styled div
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

###### How to use antd theme tokens to customize components?

Antd has very useful theme token. customize like your design system.
we can avoid styling manually too.and we can control the components by theme token. very usefully.

for override theme token, you can check it docs here [ant theme token override](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#overridetoken)

pls check it out my example

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-chihiro-q687v8)

```
export const theme = Object.freeze({
  // apply ant design theme
  token: {
    // primary color
    colorPrimary: "#5C469C",
    colorLink: "green",
    // hover color
    colorPrimaryHover: "#5C469C",
    colorLinkActive: "#00AA67",
    colorLinkHover: "#00AA67",
    wireframe: false,
    fontSize: 14,
    borderRadius: 4,
    sizeStep: 4,
    fontFamily: `'Nunito', 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif`,
    lineHeight: 1.5714285714285714,
    colorError: "#ED0131"
  },
  components: {
    Radio: {
      // orange color
      colorPrimary: "orange"
    },
    Input: {
      controlHeight: 48,
      borderRadius: 4
    },
    Button: {
      controlHeight: 60,
      borderRadius: 10
    },
    Select: {
      controlHeight: 48,
      borderRadius: 4
    }
  }
});
```

```
<ConfigProvider theme={theme}>
   <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
   </div>
   <Form>
    <Form.Item>
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
     <Radio.Group>
       <Radio value={true}>Yes</Radio>
       <Radio value={false}>No</Radio>
     </Radio.Group>
    </Form.Item>
    <Button type="primary">Send</Button>
    <Button type="ghost">Send</Button>
  </Form>
</ConfigProvider>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. 

I am struggling to fix my default bg, default text color. i am trying to implement my own dark theme which will be deafult. I tried colorBgBase, colorTextBase. But that not working