# How to consume Antd v5 theme style transitions?

Tags: themes, token, antd

Environment:
antd: 5.8.3
preact: 10.17.0

According to [docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#consume-design-token) I can use theme tokens. Which are static data.

I want to create a custom "contentEditable" element and style it like Antd.Input. But any style transitions are missing.
How can I get style transitions of Antd in my custom component?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76374478/9894625) help you?

Comment: @NoNam4, this is about consuming static theme values. For example, there are token.borderColor/borderHoverColor, and I need to write additional code to make transition between them. In earlier Antd versions I could just add "antd-input" to my custom component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this [antd git discussion](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/discussions/38753), I found an ability to turn of `"css-..."/"css-dev-only-do-not-override-..."` by providing `hashed: false` to `ConfigProvider` theme property.

But this [antd blog post](https://ant.design/docs/blog/css-in-js) and this [one](https://ant.design/docs/blog/hydrate-cssinjs) answers how styles generates and why we need hashing.

My first approach was to make [nested theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#nested-theme) with `hashed: false`, and wrap only my custom component. Add invisible Antd Input to force Antd theme generate `ant-input` style. Add `ant-input` to my custom "contentEditable".

Code example:

```
function Custom() {
  return (
    <ConfigProvider theme={{ hashed: false }}>
      <div
        contentEditable={true}
        className="ant-input"
      />
      <Input hidden />
    </ConfigProvider>
  )
}
```

This leads to `ant-input`:

- generated globally.
- re-generated on re-render (if I understood correctly).

My next step is to see [code](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/54316f719cdfb8a31118bab7d0b578043e7f71f2/components/input/Input.tsx#L96) (lines 90, 92, 96) from Antd Input component itself, and figure out how it generates styles.

It's not recommended approach at all.
But I can apply this code to my component:

```
function Custom() {
  const { getPrefixCls } = useContext(ConfigContext)
  const prefixCls = getPrefixCls('input')
  const [, hashId] = useStyle(prefixCls)
  
  return (
    <div
      contentEditable={true}
      className={classNames("ant-input", hashId)}
    />
  )
}
```