# Ant Design "ConfigProvider" with design token "ColorBorder" test failed. How to fix this

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

I am creating theme using Ant Design  "ConfigProvider" and I am giving the design token "ColorBorder" as "#ff0dff"

```js
import { ConfigProvider, Button } from "antd";
import TestTheme from "./token.json";

export function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  return <ConfigProvider theme={TestTheme}>{children}</ConfigProvider>;
}
```

but when I test that component via Jest and React Testing Library, I am getting the "PrimaryColor" instead of "ColorBorder"

```js
 it('button border should have correct value from token.json "colorBorder" ', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Button>Test</Button>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );

    expect(container.querySelector("button")).toHaveStyle({
      "border-color": "#ff0dff"
    });
  });
```

When I render that commponent via chrome, Given border color is correctly applied

How can I get the correct value ("#ff0dff") of the Button when I am testing.

I have created demo "codesandbox" to show the error:
Please check the link below
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-pine-x675xk?file=/src/App.spec.js

*Edit/Update: related to @tao comment*

Here is the screenshot of Ant Design Theme Editor, As you see "defaultBorderColor" is "#d9d9d9" and "colorBorder" is "#ff0dff"

and the preview of the button default, Pink border is correctly applied.

[image: Here is the screenshot of Ant Design Theme Editor]

Comment: `token.colorBorder` does not affect the default button's border color (and `default` is the default value for a button's `type`). It affects border color of cards, panels, dividers, pagination buttons, inputs and others. To change a default button's border color, you want to use `token.components.Button.defaultBorderColor`. I recommend their [theme editor](https://ant.design/theme-editor#Style) which allows you to see how each component would look once you make changes to the variables.

Comment: To address your testing issue: I've played a bit with your example. `getComputedStyle(container.querySelector('button')).borderColor` returns the string `'buttonface'` ([link](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-lichterman-jgkwns?file=/src/App.spec.js)), which doesn't make sense CSS-wise. Maybe it gets compiled into correct color on build, no idea. I advise you to ask on antd's repo about how to correctly test a theme's implementation (although they might answer it's not your app's responsibility to test the theme works as intended - the lib is most likely already fully covered by tests).

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies, Yeah i've checked the ThemeEditor that's where I got confused, I have updated the question with "Theme Editor Screenshot" there, Button border-color is correctly applied, I guess I don't need to pass "token.components.Button.defaultBorderColor" to the <ConfigProvider>, Please have a look when you free, thanks again for the comment,

Comment: Raised Github ticket: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/45546

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is a problem with antd itself because `getComputedStyle(container.querySelector("button"))` returns `buttonface` as border style, but with some test I could make jest to "see" component style... you'll need to pass `style` props to your components.

It doesn't matter if you set `token.components.Button.defaultBorderColor` or `token.colorBorder` or any other prop... Jest will always fail because your component does not have `style` prop itself.

You can try consoling what jest is querying to validate:

```
const element = container.querySelector("button");
console.log("queried", element);

expect(element).toHaveStyle({
  "border-color": "#ff0dff"
})
```

This console.log will print to you: `<button type="button" class="ant-btn css-dev-only-do-not-override-177njq0 ant-btn-default"> <span>Test</span> </button>` and as you can see, there's no `style` prop on it, but if you add this prop to your component:

```
<Button
  style={{borderColor: "whatever color"}}
>Test</Button
```

Now jest test will pass because now queried component will have `style` prop on it (also printed on console).

In this case I would suggest you to create a separated `.js` file with styles for each component. Here's an example:

```
// structure:
// - MyComponent1
//   - index.js 
//   - styles.js
// - MyComponent2
// ....

// styles.js
export default function Styles() {
  // it can also be a function if you need params
  const Button = {
    borderColor: "whatever color"
  }
}


// component
import Styles from 'path/to/styles'

const S = Styles()

...

<Button style={S.Button}>
  Test
</Button>
```

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but How can we verify the given border colour via `<ConfigProvider>` is properly reflected? Purpose of writing this unit test is to check values are passing properly when we pass through `<ConfigProvider>`.

Comment: Yeah, as I found out from the GitHub issue ticket I created, I understand that the issue is related to antd. Therefore, I don't think adding manual props just to pass the test case is valid use case.

Comment: You can add manual props using theme values. Import `theme` from antd and use the `useToken` hook to access all theme props. Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76374478/9894625) answer. You’re still passing manual props but using values directly from config provider.